# MySQL Error 1264 out of range value for Column 'Telnum' at row 1

Tags: mysql, varchar, mysql-error-1264

I'm literally new to SQL, trying to do a little address book as a database, issue I ran into was as described in the title.

My table: creation

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Addr (
      idAddr INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Zipcode VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      Address VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      Name VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      City VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      State VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      Telnum VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (idAddr))
```

Then, when I try to do the following

```
    INSERT INTO Addr(Zipcode, Address, Name, City, State, Telnum)
    VALUES
    ('10000', 'Evergreen Ave 100', 'John Doe', 'Columbus', 'Ohio', '9985565560');
```

I just get:

> MySQL Error 1264 out of range  value for Column 'Telnum' at row 1

Most people with this issue tried with `INT` values but I was directly trying with `VARCHAR`, I'm lost, could somebody help me out?

Comment: Which mysql version arre you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I suggest you check for triggers and qualify the table name in the insert to include the db name,